# jqGrid question

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have installed the 'jqGrid' on my PC and it works all right. The following is the screenshot of the 'jqGrid'.
Seen from screenshot, the demo page is shown on the right when clicking menu.(for example, 'xmlex.html' is displayed by clicking 'XML Data'(Under 'Loading Data')).
[image]

I only want the demo page to be displayed without the tab menu . so I open the 'xmlex.html' through web browser. but nothing is displayed on the screen. Then I copy all scripts and css links from 'jqgrid.html' to 'xmlex.html', but the page is still shown nothing.

Does anyone know How to make demo page work rather than clicking from main page in 'jqGrid'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read "My First Grid": http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:first_grid

It seems that you are on the wrong track. Just start from scratch instead of trying to modify the demo files.